# Old site posts broken after domain update

Tags: permalinks, domain

I recently updated to a different domain on my wordpress blog.

Unfortunately, all my old posts are now broken and I've tried everything.

I've ran the search and replace tool for old references and updated, still to no avail. I'm also unable to publish *new* posts at all.

https://thesimpleengineer.com

As you can see, all the posts are 404 now. I've updated permalinks as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are having permalinks issue which is usually occur due to `.htaccess` file. Can you please go to the `Settings -> Permalinks` and press update. Make sure your `.htaccess` file is writeable, usually wordpress show warning on that page if file is not writeable. If its not writeable you will get code on that page at the bottom which you have to place manually in `.htaccess` file.

`.htaccess` file can be found in your wordpress folder where `wp-config.php` file resides.

Comment: I did update permalinks. I believe htaccess is writeable as I have not received any erorrs.

Comment: Fixed by modifying the apache config

Comment: aahh. that might be the next thing i would have asked you to check the Apache config. happy that you got it resolved.